# Select to End/Beginning of Line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In most editors (including Visual Studio proper), I can use Shift+End to select all of the text from the cursor location to the end of the current line, and Shift+Home to select all text up to the beginning of the line.

These shortcuts don't seem to work out-of-the box (at least, on the Mac version). Is there some way to enable this, perhaps with a plugin or a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Strange it should work out of the box. If not, go to **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** and look for `cursorEndSelect`.

```
{"key": "shift+end", "command": "cursorEndSelect", "when": "editorTextFocus"}
```

Comment: fn+Shift+Right Arrow button combination on Mac did the job for me using out of the box settings

Comment: where's the one to set the beginning? don't see cursorStartSelect

Comment: "cursorHomeSelect" is a shortcut which selects to the start of line.

Comment: Strangely enough, I cannot set the key to `ctrl+shift+e`. It simply doesn't work, but e.g. `shift+e` does (although I really wanted to use the first one, since I'm used to emacs)

Comment: @Dmitry this did the trick for me! Tysm

Answer (score 27):

**I use following inbuilt shortcut** (VSCode 1.39.2, MacOS 10.15)

<kbd>**⌘ Command**</kbd> + <kbd>**⇧ Shift**</kbd> +  <kbd>**→ Right Arrow**</kbd>  key combination

---

You can access keyboard shortcut reference here: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

You can visit this link anytime from VS Code by navigating to

**Help** > **Keyboard Shortcuts Reference**

[image]

Comment: For some reason this works by default on MacOS but not on VS Code for me :(

Comment: Check your key bindings in the vscode to make sure there are no conflicts.

Comment: Note: the most up-to-date answer is the @norman-schultz' one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486403/6174476

Answer (score 3):

It now appears to be ⌘ Command + ⇧ Shift + ↓ Down Arrow

(MacOS Big Sur 11.6)

Answer (score 3):

The way that I set up mine is to go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and look for cursorLineEnd and cursorLineStart. Set these to with your own shortcuts for jumping to the end and beginning of a line.

Answer (score 3):

End of line: <kbd>**fn**</kbd> +  <kbd>**→ right arrow**</kbd> 
Start of line: <kbd>**fn**</kbd> +  <kbd>**← left arrow**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, We Can Use Fn + Right Arrow (For End Of Line),  Fn + Left Arrow (For Start Of Line)